# use same rewrite rule in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want use htaccess for two action.there is code

```
RewriteRule ^File-(.+).php$ FileviewerID.php?x=$1
RewriteRule ^File-(.+).php$ File.php
```

but this codes can't run with together

I want send file id to viewer and save it in db then I just want show File.php
for exam user send this file name > www.sitename.com/File-256.php
now save 256 in DB and Show File.php, I just want to do that with htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mod-rewrite cannot serve files in sequence in this way. Instead it would proceed through the list of rules and if another rule after the first one matched `FileviewerID.php`, it would be subsequently rewritten. So while it is possible to use mod_rewrite to match multiple rules on a request, it won't perform a branching into multiple requests.

Really, the proper way to handle this is in your PHP code rather than try to get the web server to do it for you.

Following a successful write to your database in `FileviewerID.php`, call `header()` in PHP to redirect to `File.php`.

```
// Fileviewer.php
// Write to database was successful, redirect to File.php...
header("Location: http://example.com/File.php");
exit();
```

#### Update after comments:

To make this work for files other than `.php`, you can still use PHP to store in the database and handle the correct redirect, but you would need to retrieve more information from the redirect in Apache. You should capture the file extension as well as the number.

```
# Capture both the number and the extension
RewriteRule ^File-(\d+)\.([A-Za-z]+)$ FileviewerID.php?x=$1&ext=$2
```

In your PHP `FielviewerID.php`, process your database action and redirect using the extension as gathered from `$_GET['ext']`.

```
// FileviewerID.php:
// Store file id in database from $_GET['x'] (hopefully using prepared statements)
// Then redirect using the file extension from $_GET['ext'], which holds an alphabetic string like "php" or "js"

// Verify that the extension is alphabetic
// Consider also checking it against an array of acceptable file extensions for 
// more reliable redirects.
if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', $_GET['ext'])) {
  header("Location: http://example.com/File.{$_GET['ext']}");
  exit();
}
else {
  // Redirect to some default location for an invalid extension
}
```

Comment: thanks for help.i know this way but some times files are .js for example file-256.js when run js file i want save number the redirect files to File.php.is not another way for working just in htaccess ? JS Files Called with Html Files

Comment: What do you mean file-256.js? That isn't matched by your rewrite rules at all (which end .php) What do you intend to do with those?  You cannot branch into multiple requests with htaccess.

Comment: for sample user put this code in himself website like this > <script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/File-256.js"></script> now i want save file number in db and redirect file to File.js  some times my files aren't just php i have .JS files too

Comment: @AmirAmini See update above.You can handle both types of redirections in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

the FileviewerID.php page must load first to save id in database

you should put a redirect in FileviewerID.php file to file.php

```
header("Location: File.php");
exit();
```

Comment: thanks for help.i know this way but some times files are .js for example  file-256.js when run js file i want save number the redirect files to File.php.is not another way for working just in htaccess ?

Comment: put you js file into your file.php and just redirect to file.php

Comment: Dear Mohammad i can't do that cause my js files are called with other html files and other websites for sample you put my jsfile in you html tags when you site opened my js file called now want save id of js file then send user to right file